# Global i18n for social app in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I'm creating a social app that may have different languages. I don't want to follow the pattern described in the Rails manual that makes use of different URL parameters for different languages. For example:

```
http://example.com/pt/books
```

I want to set things like this:

- When an user enters the site (not registered), the locale is automatically defined by the browser language profile. (Probably the current locale will be saved in a cookie). If there isn't a language that matches the browser language then the default will be english.
- When the user fills the registration form, the current language provided by the browser will be saved in the database in the users table, so even if the browser's default language is different from the logged user's default language, the last will be the main language. This time the locale won't be saved in the cookies.
- The LOGGED user will have the option to change the language in a configuration page. This will affect the database entry.
- The VISITOR user will have the option to change the language in the home page. This will affect the cookie. There will be probably a route to change this option, like:

  ```
  http://example.com/changelanguage/en
  ```

So, what's the best and simpler way to create something like this?

Comment: So sounds great in perspective of a developer, but it's an awful idea in the perspective of SEO. Your international SEO efforts will be hurt by not following the url structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [locale_setter](https://github.com/jcasimir/locale_setter) gem, it should do exactly what you're after.